# Java program using remainder operators

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, operators

I'm trying to create a java program in netbeans that will accept two integers and return a message is the first integer is a multiple of the second. So "integer1 is a multiple of integer2" or "integer1 is not a multiple of integer2". I have a little experience with HTML and am having a really hard time understanding how java works especially with using a remainder operator and if, else statements. If anyone could give me a really  simple explanation(for dummy's) of a remainder operator and examples, that would be really helpful.

Below is what I have so far but there are so many errors that I feel like none of it is right. I'm also having issues with putting brackets in the correct places.

```java
System.out.print("Enter first integer:");
int number1 = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter second integer:");
int number2 = input.nextInt();

if (number1 == number2) 
    System.out.printf("number1 is and );
}

if (number1 != number2) {
    System.out.printf("%d != %d%n number1, number2);"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The modulo operator (`%`) can be used to determine the remainder of dividing two numbers. Like,

```
int remainder = number1 % number2;
if (remainder == 0) {
    System.out.printf("%d is a multiple of %d%n", number1, number2);
} else {
    System.out.printf("%d is not a multiple of %d%n", number1, number2);
}
```

Comment: I have "cannot find symbol" errors on my lines "int number1 = input.nextInt();" and "int number2 = input.nextInt();" and an error on "System input = new Scanner(System.in); that says incompatible types:Scanner cannot be converted to system. I'm not sure what those errors mean or what I'm missing

Comment: Change the word `System` to `Scanner` at the beginning of that line @clueless